# Tracking down and fixing i18n deprecation warnings in rails 3 (cucumber 0.9.3 to blame?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, deprecated

My cucumber test passes, but leaves [this ridiculous stack trace](http://gist.github.com/658081). Just your basic `The {{key}} interpolation syntax in I18n messages is deprecated. Please use %{key} instead.` error message, but how am I to find the culprit in that list?

I never used the {{key}} syntax myself, so some gem I'm using is outdated. Please tell me which one. It's really frustrating to have so much kruft every time I run a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting that error with Authlogic and it turned out that the more recent versions of the I18n gem (0.4.x, I think) deprecated the call.

I avoided the problem by "rolling back" my I18n gem to version 0.3.7.

As to which plugin, at a guess this is the key line (line 15 on your gist):

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/responders-0.6.0/lib/responders/flash_responder.rb:115:in `set_flash_message!

Since it is the first one that is after the I18n lines, I suspect it is the one that is calling translate with the deprecated interpolation.

(Update a few minutes later):

Looking at: http://github.com/plataformatec/responders/commits/master, ...it looks like you could just upgrade to responders 0.6.2. Their commit on June 24th seems to address the issue.